# How to add time label into the message bubble?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm using JSQMessageController in my app and now I want to add time label inside of my bubbles.

[image: here]

I searched in my directories, but did not find image assets folder. But when I'm typing an image/asset name here:

I'm trying this one:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, attributedTextForCellBottomLabelAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> NSAttributedString! {
    let message: JSQMessage = self.messages[indexPath.item] as! JSQMessage
    return JSQMessagesTimestampFormatter.sharedFormatter().attributedTimestampForDate(message.date)
}
```

but this is not what I want. I want to add this label into the message bubble.

Any suggestions, even written in Objective-C?

Comment: You will have to make changes in `JSQMessageController` inorder to do that.

Comment: What do the images have to do with that?

Comment: @Losiowaty I did not understand, sorry

Comment: @HarikrishnanT can you describe your comment?

Comment: I have once used the `JSQMessageController` and as far as I know it doesn't have any method to show the time inside the bubble. So to do that you will have to edit the library yourself and add the code for that.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT unfortunately I do not know Objective C =/

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. It will work for me.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *cell = (JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *)[super collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    JSQMessage *message = [jsqmessages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    //cell.messageBubbleTopLabel.text = message.senderDisplayName;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
   [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
    NSString *strDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:message.date];
    cell.cellTopLabel.text = strDate;
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a time label, you have to change the xib file of JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellOutgoing and also for the Incoming bubbles.

Answer (score -1):

The best approach that I found was to subclass `JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellIncoming` and `JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellOutgoing`. This is very important, because the library is expecting one of those types, you will run into trouble if you subclass from `JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell` directly. BTW, I copied the existing `JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellOutgoing.xib`, `JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellIncoming.xib` and changed/renamed everything and this made it easier for me to start my customization of the cells.

Then in your JSQMessagesViewController subclass, register cell identifiers in your viewDidLoad() like so:

```
    self.outgoingCellIdentifier = [CustomCollectionViewCellOutgoing cellReuseIdentifier];
    self.outgoingMediaCellIdentifier = [CustomCollectionViewCellOutgoing mediaCellReuseIdentifier];

    [self.collectionView registerNib:[CustomCollectionViewCellOutgoing nib] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:self.outgoingCellIdentifier];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:[CustomCollectionViewCellOutgoing nib] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:self.outgoingMediaCellIdentifier];

    self.incomingCellIdentifier = [CustomCollectionViewCellIncoming cellReuseIdentifier];
    self.incomingMediaCellIdentifier = [CustomCollectionViewCellIncoming mediaCellReuseIdentifier];

    [self.collectionView registerNib:[CustomCollectionViewCellIncoming nib] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:self.incomingCellIdentifier];
```

Then in collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: you can access your custom cell:

```
[self.collectionView registerNib:[CustomCollectionViewCellIncoming nib] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:self.incomingMediaCellIdentifier];
```

Answer source link: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/1233